# Alternatives to Object Recognition Kitchen

Tags: ros, object-recognition, ros-hydro, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a hard time getting ORK to work. Are there any alternative packages in ROS Hydro for object recognition? I've searched the package list for some time but I can't find anything ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196064/alternatives-to-object-recognition-kitchen/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the roboearth project there is an object detector.
http://wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack
you can learn your own object from a 3d pointcloud and then recognize them.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-10-27**:
This seems to be only available in ROS FUERTE ...

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-10-28**:
You could try to run it on hydro. But I just noticed that the repository link is broken...